# How to write a range query for a date field with an interval on Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my current query which fetches documents which are older than 365 days from now.

```
"query": {
 "bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "match": {
        "doc_type": "AP - ACH CHECKS"
      }
    },
    {
      "range": {
        "capture_date": {
          "lte": "now-365d"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}

But I need to fetch the documents which are older than 365 days from the capture_date field. So tried like below and didn't work

```
{
  "range": {
    "capture_date": {
      "lte": "capture_date-365d"
    }
  }
}
```

What should be the correct format?

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make sense. You're searching for documents having a capture_date value older than their capture_date value... not sure I understand

Comment: well that's the requirement. I need to fetch the documents which are older than an interval, ie the retention period of those documents. And the last retention should be calculated based on the date field  "capture_date"

Comment: Ok, but then the range query cannot be on the `capture_date` field, it must be on another one, right?